# create simple js object and store them into js array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside html dom I have following structure

```
<div id="myTitles">
<ul>
  <li>
      Title:<title>A</title><br>
      Second title: <secTitle>B</secTitle><br>
      Third title: <thirdTitle>3</thirdTitle>
  </li>
  <hr>
  <li>
      Title:<title>B</title><br>
      Second title: <secTitle>C</secTitle><br>
      Third title: <thirdTitle>9</thirdTitle>
  </li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Number of list elements inside ul of myTitles div is unknown on runtime. So I'm taking  `var nrOfTitles = $('#myTitles ul li').length;` to determine how many is there.

Now, I want to create some simple javascript object which will hold those values (stored inside this semantic tags (`title`, `secTitle`, `thirdTitle`)) and store them inside js array.

Comment: Your 'semantic tags' don't appear to be real tags, which may (or may not) cause problems later. Given the (invalid) HTML you have in your question, what specific end-result do you want?

Comment: You shouldn't use those semantic tags at least for the moment in current HTML browsers and upcoming updates in one year at least

Comment: sounds like a good idea at the moment. ok, thank you. What do you suggest, how to divide them.

Comment: @user1765862 with any other html conventional tag, depending on the formatting you want to show in your web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = $("#myTitles > ul > li");

var arr = [];

items.each(function(){
    arr.push([$(this).find("title").text(),$(this).find("secTitle").text(),$(this).find("thirdTitle").text()])
})
```

With your current combination of `<li>`s it would contain:

```
[["A","B","3"],["B","C","9"]]
```

Or you can store the properties as objects:

```
var items = $("#myTitles > ul > li");

var arr = [];

items.each(function(){
    arr.push({title:$(this).find("title").text(),secTitle:$(this).find("secTitle").text(),thirdTitle:$(this).find("thirdTitle").text()})
})
```

Then you would get

```
[{title:"A",secTitle:"B",thirdTitle:"3"},{title:"B",secTitle:"C",thirdTitle:"9"}]
```

Comment: I'd personally change the array you're pushing (`[$(this).find("title").text(), ... ("thirdTitle").text()]`) to an object, like this: `{title: $(this).find("title").text() ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to conveniently create an array of objects:

```js
var obj = $('#myTitles ul li').map(function() {
    return {
        title: $(this).find('title').text(),
        secTitle: $(this).find('secTitle').text(),
        thirdTitle: $(this).find('thirdTitle').text()
    };
}).get();

alert(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTitles">
<ul>
  <li>
      Title:<title>A</title><br>
      Second title: <secTitle>B</secTitle><br>
      Third title: <thirdTitle>3</thirdTitle>
  </li>
  <hr>
  <li>
      Title:<title>B</title><br>
      Second title: <secTitle>C</secTitle><br>
      Third title: <thirdTitle>9</thirdTitle>
  </li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

But since you are using custom tags in HTML, remember to create them for IE8, if you plan so support this browser, like `document.createElement('title');`.